# How to SUM Value in cells, while ignoring Character in Excell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I will have table going from C7 to the AG7, that will have values like: G20 B34 P55 O33. I need to sum those numbers, but i don't know how to Ignore Letters G B P and O, also I have empty cells with no value.  The end result should be 142.

Id like to Sum those numbers in AI7 column.

Is this possible I've looked everywhere couldn't find what I need.

Comment: Is it always one letter and the first character?

Comment: Thats right one character followed by number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--MID(C7:AG7,2,5),0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm, Thank you sir you are truly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use a helper row, then you could consider this, which extracts the numbers by avoiding the first character :

[image]